# How to know the video resolution, which is coming over UDP ts stream?

Tags: udp, gstreamer, mpeg

I am streaming yuv file over udp as mpegstream.

and, i am receiving that using below pipeline,

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=8765 ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux ! avdec_h264 ! appsink
```

At, appsink, i am receiving the video buffer. But, now i would like to know the incoming video stream resolution.

How can i find the resolution of the incoming video.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Have you read about GstCaps?

Comment: yeah, i read about caps to negotiate the stream.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sinkPad = gst_element_get_static_pad (Sink, "sink");

sinkCaps = gst_pad_get_current_caps (sinkPad);

UU_PRINT("Caps :: %s", gst_caps_to_string (sinkCaps));

str = gst_caps_get_structure(sinkCaps, 0);

if((!gst_structure_get_int (str, "width", &width))  || (gst_structure_get_int (str, "height", &height)))
{
    UU_PRINT("No Width/Height are Available in the Incoming Stream Data !!");
}

UU_PRINT("Width :: %d Hieght %d", width, height);

gst_caps_unref(sinkCaps);
```

Comment: What element is the "Sink" in your first line above?

Comment: it is appsink element, and this function is a call back function of appsink, with signal new-sample

Comment: But  you said you need the "incoming" aka encoded video stream resolution ? Appsink will process the decoded video.

Comment: after decoding, at sink element, i will get the resolution. That is nothing but incoming resolution. right?

Comment: depends on what you mean by "incoming resolution". Some hw decoders I've seen output frames to maintain the alignment (eg. memory layouts in embedded systems, etc  for a faster access) . Eg. If the encoded resolution says 632x480, the decoded output could be 640*480 (width 16 byte aligned). If the decoder s "says" it has padded the width by x bytes ( which is called stride), then it's fine, otherwise you would never know.

Comment: I am encoding some resolution say(640X480), using x264enc and mpegtsmux and then streaming over UDP, at receiving end, i am attaching an appsink element after decoder (avdec_h264). at that i am analyzing the resolution. It is same as the input resolution while encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event probe on the sink pad of the video decoder. The API needs a handler. Check for GST_EVENT_CAPS inside your handler.

Here's the API:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstPad.html#gst-pad-add-probe